# PDFTron displays blurry pages when connectivity is slow

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, pdftron

My PDFTron web Application(website) displays blurry pages when connectivity is slow on android phones in any browser(like chrome). So there is any way/idea to overcome this issue, please suggest.

Comment: You are asking about Android, but the question is tagged asp.net... are you viewing PDF files through the browser? If so, is the browser inside an application? Also if in the browser are you using PDFTron's Webviewer? And are you trying to view PDF directly or are you converting to XOD files first?

Or are you using PDFViewCtrl.OpenURLAsync?

Comment: i am browsing my website in crome browser on android device. not inside any android application. and using PDFTron's Webviewer in my web application. And i am converting it to XOD files first in my web application. not using PDFViewCtrl.OpenURLAsync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you see a thumbnail while WebViewer is still downloading the file.

1) What version of WebViewer are you using?
2) Do you eventually see the full resolution page?
3) Can you reproduce this on an android with fast connection?

If 2 & 3 are negative a link to your environment or modified sample will help us reproduce the problem in house and assist you further.